# Earn from education learned by pirated sources

Tags: money, piracy, education

ASSALAM U ALAIKUM!

Before 2 or 3 years when I was very young and didn't know programming and wanted to learn it so I told my Uncle and he pirated me some courses from which I learned and now I am getting real money from my hard work and projects but now I know that piracy is HARAM should I discontinue using the language(C#) and just learn another and spend other 2 - 3 years to get back to where I am now or something...

by the way I was 13 or 14 at the time. Now I mostly avoid pirating since I know it's HARAM but can I use my education or not?

**EIDT**
Not everything I learned is from pirated, it's like a  mix of both. Out of all the courses he downloaded I only learnt from 2 and all the rest from youtube, pluralsight  etc...
even the basics like if you can argue that the basics were from pirated so before C# I learned JAVA which is someone know are very similar so even the basics I learned from JAVA were also carried on to C#.
If I have to spend another 2 to 3 years learning other language it's okay, at least I'll know my income for my projects would be HALAL. :)
but I just need to be sure before I reinvent the wheel.

**EDIT 2**
I know that piracy is haram and I've switched to using non pirated courses now but I want to know what is done is forgiven or I should forget all that what I've got from those pirated content

Comment: I also used pirated courses (did not have money to buy). So, I bought monthly subscriptions after getting job and paying (to pluralsight) even though I am not using it - considering it's the money I should have paid before...

Comment: Islam considers knowledge as a common property. So the scholarly view on piracy or breaking copy-rights goes from considering them halal to makruh or maybe haram if there's a declaration that the content has a copy right. See also [Do you need permission to download Islamic videos from the internet](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/52872/do-you-need-permission-to-download-islamic-videos-from-the-internet). Furthermore scholare don't consider an income haram if you got the job in a haram manner as long as you do your job well.

Answer (score 0):

Alaikum salaam

Piracy in some cases is a marketing tool for companies. If you told others about those resources and drove sales for the company, they profited from your piracy.

Morally, if you want to 'make things right' you can do so easily by simply paying for those resources now.

I wrote a much more detailed answer about [piracy as a marketing tool](https://qr.ae/TWKXfY) on Quora a while back which may be of interest to you.