# Lawful and unlawful money

Tags: halal-haram

I need to ask few questions which help me out to undersand many things Insha Allah
Scenario:
If a person is a software developer and come to know that piracy is haram and then suddenly he use the **pirated software(Windows)** to download opensource software(Linux).
Questions:
1-What is the Islamic ruling on the money he earns from the software  development using Linux  as the source of downloading the opensource software is Unlawful that is pirated software (windows)?
2-The knowledge he gain which will be helpful for him in the **Lawful earning of money** from the **unlawful source(Pirated Windows and different software)**?
3-Does he need to quit the whole profession as he learnt every thing from the unlawful source(pirated softwares) but the knowledge helps him to earn lawful money after using the legal softwares
4-Does he need to charity all money when he don't have understanding of Islam and he unknowingly use the pirated softwares for his profession?
5- can he purchase legal things from the unlawful money and later charity the unlawful money from the lawful money

I hope some one will help me out
Thanks 
Regards 
Muhammad Harris

Answer (score 1):

In Islam your income being halal or haram depends on whether you earned it by your own effort or not in first place.

So to earn halal money you need:

- to earn it by your own effort.
- have a halal job means for example you should not run a riba business or sell alcohol or more general earn your money from something that Allah clearly forbid.

As for the matter of piracy there are plenty answers on the site I suggest you to read this one: [Do you need permission to download islamic videos from the Internet?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/52872/do-you-need-permission-to-download-islamic-videos-from-the-internet/52886#52886) and there might be others.

I'd say if you used for example windows just to download and install linux and removed it from your pc you should be on the safe site. But you should repent from this misuse to be even safer. Note that in case you used pirated software while you are able to buy it legally the matter might be different, but Allah knows best.

Comment: is stealing allowed in Islam ??? Is using of pirated softwares not stealing ?

Comment: Question 2-
The knowledge he gain which will be helpful for him, in the Lawful earning of money from the unlawful source(Pirated Windows and different software)?

Comment: Question3- Open source software are not available to sell??where shall i purchase it as i need some software or operating system to download all open source softwares

Comment: Stealing is not allowed in Islam, but in Islam there's no copy right system on knowledge so if you gain (useful) knowledge the source basically doesn't play a role. However some say if copy right is clearly written one should not break it. Gained (useful) knowledge is always halal.

Comment: Thanks for giving me sound answers and enough time.

Comment: Question:Is knowledge and Learning a same thing???
I will give one example soon according to which i can make you firm understanding which i want to say ?

Comment: Question i need to know under what circumstances a person can go to unlawful things?
Along with i need to know the answer of question no 3
Open source software are not available in the market?where shall i purchase it as i need some software or operating system to download all open source softwares in that case a person can use unlawful operating system(windows) in order to download Lawful operating system 
Question 4- A person need to give charity to whole unlawful money which he earn through the above source ??

Comment: What hinders you from downloading it from an internet coffee? Yeah earning and spreeding knowledge and learning is regarded as similar and is halal, as long as the content is useful and halal.

Comment: I ask the internet cafe weather they are using licensed windows they say no i ask them weather there is any internet cafe where i can use it they say no

Comment: Well it sounds strange, but you may have gone to far asking this however you did the best possible may Allah reward you. I'm quit sure that you may find enough scholars saying that it was not necessary to ask about a licensed windows. Nevertheless using something doubtful or haram should be the last option. So you may ask. I mean there are about 2% linux users in the world maybe you know some of them. You don't need windows for download. And some Linux Distributions can be bought (optionally).

Comment: shall i put some more questions if you allow me ??

Comment: Hm... it is better to ask different questions as new posts especially if the topic is a bit broad as in our case.

Comment: First of all thanks for giving me enough time.
I need to ask last thing according to this website shall i purchase Linux from the market The website is given below:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/521239/is-it-okay-to-sell-linux-distributions