# Making software using pirated software to make parts of it

Tags: money, software, piracy

I am making some software. I have started this before I found out that using pirated software is bad. The logo I made is made with pirated software. Everything else was free. I intend to earn money from this software. Should I re-make the logo without pirated software?

Comment: Please search on the site before asking a question duplicate questions don't make the site better.

Comment: I do not think there is the same question on this site. I am specifically saying that I am saying that i used pirated software to make parts of my software. Should i replace those parts? That is my question. @Sassir please give me a question which is the smae as this.

Comment: See for example [Do you need permission to download islamic videos from the internet](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/52872/do-you-need-permission-to-download-islamic-videos-from-the-internet/52886#52886) which is very similar and actually ansewers your inquiry. For further informagion about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].