# Is it haram to download paid courses in free?

Tags: halal-haram, internet, piracy

So there are many websites which uploads video courses in their websites in free of costs that are downloaded from other paid websites like Udemy, Skillshare, Lynda etc. Though this courses are given free of cost actually they are paid courses.

1. Is it permissible or haram for me to download courses from the free websites and learn from them??
2. Is it permissible or haram for me to share those courses with other peoples so that thay can have those courses??

Comment: Please check the site before asking a question duplicate.

Comment: [This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/52872/do-you-need-permission-to-download-islamic-videos-from-the-internet) might give an answer of this question.

Comment: I could give an Islamic answer, but I won't. This is against all copyright rules. I help creators find these courses that are `free` and get them taken down. If you were to buy the course you are given ONE license and only for the buyer, and not to be resold or passed on.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be haraam in that sense that you are not paying the royalties or payments you are supposed to give. As I remember a famous hadith of prophet Muhammad, " Pay the laborer before his sweats have vanished". The same goes here! isn't it?

Check the policy, it is ok to share to some extent. That is not a problem if you do it legally. Or just ask them to clarify to what extent you want to share them. Mostly students get a discount when you ask them.

Comment: So if i purchase a course online and download it than give one copy to my friends it will be haram?? Means i can not give this to anyone? If anyone ask me for course i have to tell him to buy the course?/

Comment: @S K clearly answered your question in his second paragraph

Comment: @S K what's your opinion on say pirated movies and tv shows?

Comment: @EPICTubeHD, when did movies and tv shows exactly become halal? For debate let's assume you are only interested in Islamic Q/A masla'a TV shows, I believe they are always free :)

Comment: @SK sorry but who said movies and tv shows are haram?? I get there's a lot of bad apples in media, but regardless this is a unfair generalisation. Everything has good or bad, as muslims we must enjoin upon the good and avoid the evil.