# Is reading copyrighted books online haram in my case?

Tags: piracy

Is reading copyrighted books online haram in my case?

Pretty similar to an older post on this forum. There’s a book I want to read that’s in Japanese AND has an official English translation. There are also others that don’t have official English translations. I’ve asked my parents if they could buy it. They do have the money and were going to buy it, but after doing a quick Google and finding out that book can just be read for free online they told me to do that.

I respect their decision and politely told them that this type of thing is against Islam. They told me not to worry since it’s ‘only against Islam if you make money off of it’.

I as a teen don’t have any money, so I can’t exactly go about buying it either. I did a bit of digging online and found I could rent each chapter of the book for 48 hours on a Japanese site by the official publisher. They have their own system where you can gain the currency to read the chapters through ways other that direct payment (e.g watching ads and a daily free chapter). It doesn’t seem to be too much of a chore so **I wanted to ask if it is permissible to legally access the chapters in Japanese but read the English through ‘read for free’ websites.**

Edit: I’d try to abide by the rules and make it as similar as possible to the experience of just reading the Japanese by not going past the 48 hour limit and renting the chapter again if I needed more time to read it.

Comment: If you get the book illegally, then this will be counted as stealing. However, if it's not a crime, then you can read it, as long there is no bad things.

Comment: I think your inquiry is well addressed in [Do you need permission to download Islamic videos from the internet](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/52872/do-you-need-permission-to-download-islamic-videos-from-the-internet).